# Nothing showing with PhaserJS

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to learn phaser js and I'm following the tutorial but when run my code nothing is showing on the web browser. Here is my code:

```
    <html>

<script type="text/javascript">
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 1280,
    height: 720,
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    }
};

var game = Phaser.Game(config);

function preload ()
{
    this.load.image('player', 'assets/player.png');
    this.load.image('sky', 'assets/sky.png');
}
function create ()
{
    player = this.physics.add.image(640, 360);
    this.add.image(640, 360, 'sky');
    player.setBounce(0.2);
    player.setColliderWorldBounds(true);
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you need some more assistance, or is you question answered?

Answer (score 0):

There are some points, that could cause problems(and/or are problematic), and/or should be checked:

1. your placing the **sky** ontop of the **player**. The order in which you add assets / images is important.
2. `player = this.physics.add.image(640, 360)` creates a image, with a physics-object, but if you don't pass a key, the image will not be displayed.  that line change it to `player = this.physics.add.image(640, 360, 'player');`
3. If you don't configure `physics` the application will crash. (check the browser console for an error message), **solution,** change the configuration to this:

   ```
   var config = {
      type: Phaser.AUTO,
      width: 1280,
      height: 720,
      scene: {
          preload: preload,
          create: create,
          update: update
      },
      physics: {
          default: 'arcade',
          arcade: {
               gravity: { y: 300 }
          }
      },
   };
   ```

**btw.:** the official phaser examples, are very helpful and showcase many functions of phaser in a tiny scope https://phaser.io/examples, they helped my to get started with phaser.

***p.s.:** when developing with html and javascript the browser-console is your best friend / tool, it shows error's and can help with debugging and alot more.*